# How do I append to an array that is a value of a key in a dictionary?

Tags: arraylist, vbscript, scripting.dictionary

If I set up a dictionary as such:

```
set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

I ask a user his name.

```
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "What is your name: "
name = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
```

I then ask the user for five numbers.

```
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a number: "
    num1 = cint(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a number: "
    num2 = cint(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a number: "
    num3 = cint(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a number: "
    num4 = cint(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a number: "
    num5 = cint(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
```

and place the five prompted numbers into any array using *ArrayList*

```
Set myArrayList = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )
myArrayList.Add num1
myArrayList.Add num2
myArrayList.Add num3
myArrayList.Add num4
myArrayList.Add num5
```

If I add a key with `name` in the dictionary that I set up.

```
myDict.Add name
```

Can I add `myArrayList` as a value to `name` in the `myDict` dictionary I previously set up.

and if so,how can I append or add to `myArrayList` if I were to loop the five number questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a dictionary can be a primitive value as well as an array or an object (like an `ArrayList`), either like this:

```
myDict.Add name, myArrayList
```

or like this:

```
Set myDict(name) = myArrayList
```

You can work with the object by selecting it by name. The following would append the value 42 as a new element to the array list:

```
myDict(name).Add 42
```

You could also put a new (empty) array list into the dictionary and append your numbers afterwards:

```
Set myDict(name) = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a number: "
myDict(name).Add CInt(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine)
...
```